# Изменение фото вместе с миниатюрой

Tags: javascript

Как изменить этот скрипт, чтобы главная фотка менялась вместе с миниатюрой?

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
var current = 1;
var kolvo = 3; //kol-vo Image
tumb = new Array();
tumb[0] = new Image();
tumb[0].src = "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Мои документы/Фото2118.jpg" //1 Image
tumb[1] = new Image();
tumb[1].src = "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Мои документы/Фото2119.jpg" //2 Image
tumb[2] = new Image();
tumb[2].src = "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Мои документы/kinopoisk.ru-Tears-of-the-Sun-463088--w--1600.jpg" //3 Image

function goForward() {
    if (current < kolvo) {
        current++;
        document.images['smal'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;
    }
}

function goBack() {
    if (current > 1) {
        current--;
        document.images['smal'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;
    }
}

function hiAll() {
    document.images['bigs'].src = document.images['smal'].src;}
</SCRIPT>

<TABLE cellSpacing=5 cellPadding=5 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD rowSpan=2>
<IMG height=160 src="file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Мои документы/Фото2118.jpg" width=240 border=0 name="bigs">
</TD>
<TD align=middle>
<A href="javascript:hiAll();"><IMG height=300 src="file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Мои документы/Фото2118.jpg" width=500 border=0 name="smal"></A>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD class=txt>
<A href="javascript:goBack();"><<</A>
<A href="javascript:goForward();">>></A>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
var current = 1;
var kolvo = 4; //kol-vo Image
tumb = new Array();
tumb[0] = new Image();
tumb[0].src = "01.jpg" //1 Image
tumb[1] = new Image();
tumb[1].src = "02.jpg" //2 Image
tumb[2] = new Image();
tumb[2].src = "05.jpg" //3 Image
tumb[3] = new Image();
tumb[3].src = "07.jpg" //3 Image

function goForward() {
    current++;
    if (current > kolvo) {
    current=1;
    }
    document.images['small'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;
    document.images['bigimage'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;
    }

function goBack() {
    current--;
    if (current < 1) {
    current=kolvo;
    }
    document.images['small'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;
    document.images['bigimage'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;
    }
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<TABLE cellSpacing=5 cellPadding=5 border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD rowSpan=2>
<IMG src="01.jpg" height=160 width=214 border=0 name="small">
</TD>
<TD align=middle>
<IMG src="01.jpg" height=480 width=640 border=0 name="bigimage">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD class=txt>
<A href="javascript:goBack();"><<</A>
<A href="javascript:goForward();">>></A>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Денис, спасибо большое! У вас все получилось, а подскажите, как убрать эту миниатюру.

Comment: Убрать строки

    <TD rowSpan=2>
    <IMG src="01.jpg" height=160 width=214 border=0 name="small">
    </TD>
     document.images['small'].src = tumb[current - 1].src;

Еще прочитать книгу по html и javascript.